# Maximize parameter $a$ such that inequality is still satisfied

Tags: polynomials, optimization, constraints

Consider the following inequality
$$ax^5 -bx^2 +2x -1 \leq 0$$
with the following constraints on the parameters $a,b$
$$a>0\\
b\in \left(0,\tfrac{1}{2}\right)\\$$
and the constraint on the variable $x$
$$x\in [1,\infty)$$
I want to do the following: For any given $b\in\left(0,\tfrac{1}{2}\right)$, find the largest $a>0$ such that there exists an $x\in[1,\infty)$ such that the inequality is satisfied. I now realize that this $x$ will then saturate the equality, so essentially: Given $b$, I am looking for the maximal $a$ such that the polynomial $ax^5 -bx^2 +2x -1$ still has roots $\geq$ 1.

For notational clarity: I am looking for the functional behavior of $a$ as a function of $b$ in the sense
$$a(b)= \{\max_{a>0}a \;|\;ax^5 -bx^2 +2x -1\leq0 , x\geq1 \}$$
in the interval $b\in \left(0,\tfrac{1}{2}\right)$.

If it's not possible to solve exactly, I would also appreciate to understand the scaling behavior of $a(b)$.
As a first step, even a numerical analysis would help, I simply lack the Mathematica skills do get what I want.

Comment: I don't think there is a maximum, maybe you want the minimum

Comment: hmm, as far as I can see the minimum is attained for $a=0$ or rather $a\to 0$ since the resulting equation $-bx^2+2x-1=0 $ always has a solution $x>1$ for the range of $b$ values I am interested in: (see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-bx%5E2+%2B2x+-1+%3D+0%2C+x%3E1%2C++0%3Cb%3C1%2F2)

Comment: I did observation in GeoGebra. You´re right @Marsl , for any $b\in(0,0.5)$ exists $a>0$ such that the equation has a solution larger than $1.$ If an $a_0$ satisfies, then each $a<a_0$ satisfies as well. It is legitimate to ask for the maximal $a(b).$  I do not have its formula right now. It seems that $a(b)$ is an increasing function of $b.$

Comment: yep, I agree, $a(b)$ must be increasing with $b$. In particular, $a(b)=b$ doesnt work! If you have any ideas how one would explore the rough behavior of $a(b)$ even numerically, that would already be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\,p(x)=ax^5-bx^2+2x-1\,$ with $\,a \gt 0\,$ and $\,0 \lt b \lt \frac{1}{2}\,$.

- $\,p(0) = - 1 \lt 0\,$ and $\,p(1) = a - b + 1 \gt 0\,$ since $\,a \gt 0 \gt b-1\,$.
- $\,p'(x)=5ax^4-2bx+2 \gt 0\,$ for $\,0 \le x \le 1\,$ since $\,-2bx+2 \ge-2b+2 \gt 0\,$.

By the rule of signs, $\,p'(x)\,$ has no negative roots, and $\,0\,$ or $\,2\,$ positive ones.

- If $\,p'(x)\,$ has no positive roots, then $\,p'(x) \gt 0\,$ on $\,\mathbb R^+\,$, so $\,p(x)\,$ is strictly increasing and, given $\,p(1) \gt 0\,$, it follows that $\,p(x)\,$ has no roots $\,x \ge 1\,$.
- If $\,p'(x)\,$ has $\,2\,$ positive roots, they must both be $\,\ge 1\,$ since $\,p'(x) \gt 0\,$ on $\,[0,1]\,$.

Therefore, a necessary condition for $\,p(x)\,$ to have a root $\,\ge 1\,$ is for $\,p'(x)\,$ to have $\,2\,$ real roots, which will then both be $\,x_{1,2}'\gt 1\,$.

$\,p''(x)=20ax^3-2b\,$ has a unique real root $\,x_1'' = \sqrt[3]{\frac{b}{10a}} \gt 0\,$, which corresponds to a minimum of $\,p'(x)\,$. The sufficient condition for $\,p'(x)\,$ to have $\,2\,$ real roots is that the value at the minimum point be negative or zero $\,p'(x'') \le 0\,$:

$$
\require{cancel}
0 \ge p'(x'') = 5\cancel{a}\frac{b}{10\cancel{a}}\sqrt[3]{\frac{b}{10a}} - 2b\sqrt[3]{\frac{b}{10a}}+2 = -\frac{3b}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{b}{10a}} + 2
$$
$$
\iff\quad\quad a \le a_0 = \frac{27 b^4}{640} \tag{1}
$$

Piecing together the findings above, when $\,(1)\,$ is satisifed, $\,p(x)\,$ will have a root in $\,(0,1)\,$, then will increase to a maximum at $x_1' \gt 1$, decrease to a minimum at $\,x_2' \ge x_1'\,$, then increase to $\,+\infty\,$. The necessary and sufficient condition for a root $\,\gt 1\,$ to exist is that $\,p(x_2') \le 0\,$, and in that case there will be two such roots on either side of $\,x_2'\,$.

When $\,a \to 0\,$ the equation reduces to a quadratic with two real roots $\,\gt 1\,$. As $\,a\,$ increases, the dominant term in $\,p(x)\,$ is $\,ax^5\,$ when $\,x \gt 1\,$, so the "∿" shaped graph of $\,p(x)\,$ gets "pulled up". The two real roots get closer and closer to one another, until at some point they become equal then vanish altogether. The point where that happens is when $\,p(x)\,$ has a double root i.e. its [discriminant](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=discriminant+a+x%5E5+-+b+x%5E2+%2B+2+x+-+1+) becomes $\,0\,$:

$$
\begin{align}
0 = \Delta &= a^2 (3125 a^2 + 4500 a b^2 - 12800 a b + 8192 a + 108 b^5 - 108 b^4)
\\ &= a^2 \big(3125 a^2 + 4(1125 b^2 - 3200 b + 2048) a + 108 b^4(b-1)\big) = a^2\,q(a)
\end{align}
$$

The part in parenthesis $\,q(a)\,$ is a quadratic in $\,a\,$, and it can be verified that its discriminant $\,\delta \gt 0\,$ for $\,0 \lt b \lt \frac{1}{2}\,$, so the quadratic has two real roots of opposite signs $\,a_1 \lt 0 \lt a_2\,$ since their product is negative. Then the condition for $\,p(x)\,$ to have real roots is (courtesy [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+3125+a%5E2+%2B+4%281125+b%5E2+-+3200+b+%2B+2048%29+a+%2B+108+b%5E4%28b-1%29+%3D+0+for+a)):

$$
a \le a_2 = - \frac{2}{3125}\left(2048 - 3200 b + 1125 b^2 - (32 - 5 b)(16 - 15 b)\sqrt{16 - 15 b}\right) \tag{2}
$$

Taking the minimum between $\,(1),(2)\,$ gives in the end $\,a \le a_{max} = \min\left(a_0, a_2\right)\,$.

For verification, consider for example $\,b=\frac{1}{4}\,$, then [$\,a_0 =$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=27+b%5E4+%2F+640+where+b+%3D+1%2F4) $27/163840\,$, [$\,a_2=$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-%282+%281125+b%5E2+-+3200+b+-+sqrt%28-%285+b+-+32%29%5E2+%2815+b+-+16%29%5E3%29+%2B+2048%29%29%2F3125+where+b+%3D+1%2F4) $3/50000\,$, so $\,a_{max} = 3/50000\,$. Indeed, for $\,a=a_{max}\,$ the equation [becomes](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=factor+3%2F50000+x%5E5+-+x%5E2+%2F+4+%2B+2+x+-+1):

$$
\frac{3}{50000} x^5 - \frac{1}{4} x^2 + 2 x - 1 = \frac{1}{50000}(x - 10)^2 (3 x^3 + 60 x^2 + 900 x - 500)
$$

When $\,a = a_{max}\,$ the equation has the double root $\,x=10\,$, and for $\,0 \lt a \lt a_{max}\,$ it will have two distinct real roots $\,\gt 1\,$, in addition to the third real root in $\,(0,1)\,$ which always exists.

---

[ *EDIT* ] $\;$ It can be [verified](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=3125+a%5E2+%2B+4%281125+b%5E2+-+3200+b+%2B+2048%29+a+%2B+108+b%5E4%28b-1%29+where+a+%3D+27+b%5E4+%2F+640) that $\,q(a_0) \gt 0\,$ when $\,0 \lt b \lt \frac{1}{2}\,$, which means $\,a_0 \not\in [a_1,a_2]\,$, and given that $\,a_0\,$ is positive it follows that $\,a_0 \gt a_2\,$, so in the end $\,a_{max}=\min(a_0,a_2)=a_2\,$.

Comment: Nice solution (+1). I started as you did, but did not think of discriminant of the quintic. GeoGebra gives the same values for your example. Just a note: since OP asks a negative value of $f(x),$ this $a(b)$ is a supremum.

Comment: @user376343 Thanks. I actually started with the discriminant, but then I had to justify that the double root in question "happens" to be a real root in $\,[1,\infty)\,$ in order to conclude.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Lagrange multipliers. First we make some variable changes:

$$
\cases{
a=u^2\\
x = v^2
}
$$

so we arrive at the lagrangian

$$
L(u,v,\lambda,e) = u^2+\lambda\left(u^2v^{10}-b v^4+2v^2-1+e^2\right)
$$

and the stationary points are given by the solutions to

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 u\left(\lambda v^{10}+1\right)&=&0 \\
 \lambda\left(5 u^2 v^9-2 b v^3+2v\right) &=&0\\
 u^2 v^{10}-b v^4+2 v^2-1+e^2&=&0 \\
 e \lambda&=&0  \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

so we have the options

$$
\cases{
2 u\left(\lambda  v^{10}+1\right)=0\Rightarrow\{ u = 0\}\cup \{\lambda v^{10}+1=0\}\\
 e \lambda = 0\Rightarrow \{ \lambda = 0\}\cup\{ e = 0\}
}
$$

now multiplying $5 u^2 v^9-2 b v^3+2v$  by $v$ and the third by $5$ we have

$$
\cases{
5 u^2 v^{10}-2 b v^4+2v^2 = 0\\
5u^2 v^{10}-5b v^4+10 v^2-5+5e^2=0 
}
$$

so we follow with an easy polynomial and after some substitutions we arrive at the solution.

$$
a = f(b) = \frac{1}{625} \left(30 \left(\sqrt{16-15 b}-15\right) b^2+32 \left(40-7 \sqrt{16-15 b}\right) b+\frac{1024}{5} \left(\sqrt{16-15 b}-4\right)\right)
$$

Follows a plot showing $a = f(b)$

[image]

Comment: Cesareo, this is an interesting approach. However, the question is to find $a$ as a function of $b.$

Comment: @user376343 The answer was adapted accordingly to the OP.

Comment: @Cesareo That's another nice way to frame it (+1). Though the "*easy polynomial*" step is a bit less straightforward than it may sound (and, just to nitpick, don't know that the term $+5e^2$ belongs there). One thing needed to close it when going this way would be to show that $\,0 \lt a \lt f(b)\,$ is indeed the range corresponding to two real $\,x \ge 1\,$ roots.

Comment: @user376343 $e$ is a slack variable needed to transform the inequality $u^2v^{10}-b v^4+2v^2-1\le 0$ into the equation $u^2v^{10}-b v^4+2v^2-1+e^2=0$. The polynomial handling is facilitated by using conveniently the options.